# flotante con muchos decimales en un array

Tags: python, python-3.x

tengo un problema y es que tengo un programa en python donde hago calculos de diferentes tipos, el caso es que uno de estos calculos me da como resultado un flotante con 16 decimales y al momento de almacenar este numero en un arreglo no lo hace bien.

Este es el numero original que me arroja un cierto calculo 1.2246467991473532e-16

y esto es como se almacena en el array 1.2246467991473532e

lo cual me da conflicto al acceder posteriormente a este numero y tampoco puedo hacer uso de round porque si trunco hasta un digito antes de la "e" pues es un numero completamente diferente al original.

Hay alguna manera de que se almacene este numero completo en el array?

---

para los que pidieron que muestre el codigo, aqui esta:

```
import numpy as np

a=1.2246467991473532e-16
matriz=np.matrix([["x","y","z",a],
                  ["x","y","z",a]])
m=[[-0.0, 0.0], [-0.30901699437494756, -0.9510565162951535], [-1.0, 1.2246467991473532e-16], [-1.3090169943749477, -0.9510565162951534]]

c=0.9510565162951535
matriz[1,0],matriz[0,1]=float(m[3][1])+c,c+float(m[3][1])



print(matriz)
```

resultado:

```
[['x' '1.1102230246251565e' 'z' '1.2246467991473532e-16']
 ['1.1102230246251565e' 'y' 'z' '1.2246467991473532e-16']]
```

Comment: Hola Benji, ¿podrías agregar un [mcve] para poder reproducir el problema? No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, tanto usando una lista (`a = [1.2246467991473532e-16]`) como un array de NumPy (`a = np.array([1.2246467991473532e-16])`) podemos almacenar sin problemas ese float sin perder precisión...

Comment: Deduzco que el array en cuestión debe de ser de strings y que estás truncando de algún modo la longitud de esos strings a 19 caracteres, por lo que no se te almacena completo. De otro modo no entiendo qué estás haciendo, ya que un flotante en un array de flotantes en realidad se almacenaría en binario y nunca faltarían "caracteres".  Sería necesario ver tu código para concretar el problema y ayudarte a resolverlo.

Comment: ya lo puse mas abajo, para que chequen

Comment: Bengi las respuestas solo pueden usarse para responder a la pregunta, para añadir información a la pregunta debes usar el botón [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/137825/edit) y añadirla en la propia pregunta. Por otro lado, el problema es que estas intentando almacenar floats donde antes defines cadenas, en un array de NumPy no se puede cambiar el tipo, por lo que tus floats son casteados a str. ¿Por qué almacenas cadenas que luego intentas substituir con floats? No se muy bién cual es la idea de tu código pero deberías replantearlo usando otra aproximación o usar listas.